# Error de permisos al querer subir documentos en django usando apache en redhat

Tags: django, apache, permisos

Al querer publicar mi sitio web en un servidor redhat con apache, no puedo escribir datos en la bd, seguí este tutorial:

https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/how-to-install-django-with-apache-on-centos-7/#configure-apache-for-django

ya probé darle permisos con chmod 755 db.sqlite3, también probé asignado como propietario del directorio y documentos a apache, ya reinicié los servicios con los comando systemctl restart httpd y systemctl enable httpd

Pude crear un superuser con python manage.py, pero al querer entrar al admin, me sale el error de que no tengo permiso de escritura.

Mi wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Mi django.conf

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Alias /static /opt/djangoproject/Convocatoria/static_cdn
Alias /media /opt/djangoproject/Convocatoria/MEDIA
Alias /favicon.ico /opt/djangoproject/Convocatoria/static_cdn/Icono.png

<Directory /opt/djangoproject/Convocatoria/static_cdn>
  Require all granted
</Directory>

  <Directory /opt/djangoproject/Convocatoria/MEDIA>
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /opt/djangoproject/Convocatoria/Un_Formulario/project>
   <Files wsgi.py>
       Require all granted
   </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess Convocatoria python-path=/opt/djangoproject:/opt/djangoproject/djangoprojectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup Convocatoria
WSGIScriptAlias / 
/opt/djangoproject/Convocatoria/Un_Formulario/project/wsgi.py
```

Comment: ¿Que usuario es el propietario del archivo db.sqlite3? Yo pobaría con el propietario root y grupo www-data, creo que con esto y permisos 644 te funcionaría

Comment: Directorio del proyecto, db.sqlite3 son de apache, creo que no tengo configurado el wsgi bien o es problema de configuración de apache por que no puedo agregar nada con apache, ya probé subiendo documentos con mi base de datos hecha con mariaDB

Comment: Revisalo y si lo ves adecuado, edita la preguntar para aportar la información que ncesitemos para ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucioné deshabilitando SELinux
/etc/selinux/config

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#       targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#       mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```